# Can't retrieve data on a url with "sc-domain" using google search api

Tags: google-search-console, google-search-api

While using

```
$sites = $searchConsole->sites->listSites();
```

I confirmed that I have `siteFullUser` access

But when I try to get information on a URL with this code

```
$serviceSearchConsole = new Google_Service_SearchConsole($client);
$queryURL = new Google_Service_SearchConsole_InspectUrlIndexRequest();
$queryURL->setSiteUrl($projecturl);
$queryURL->setInspectionUrl($url);
$result = $serviceSearchConsole->urlInspection_index->inspect($queryURL);
```

I get this error: You do not own this site, or the inspected URL is not part of this property

Worth mentioning that I do have access, and I get information about keywords and impressions, etc... just can't get information on URLs. I assume it's a problem since the site is confirmed by DNS and not by http\https URL. but I try many forms of URL and sc-domain and nothing works.